# How do I publish and update to a users facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a status update to a users facebook timeline, however then I run this, nothing happens.

```
   require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
   'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
   'sharedSession' => true,
    'trustForwarded' => true,
   ));
 $response = $facebook->api(
 'me/news.publishes'
 'POST',
 array(
  'article' => "http://samples.ogp.me/434264856596891"
 )
);
```

Comment: Have you logged in a user first? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

try to replace "news.publishes" with "feed" , so the code will be

```
$response = $facebook->api(
 'me/feed'
 'POST',
 array(
  'article' => "http://samples.ogp.me/434264856596891"
 )
);
```